# Сообщение исключено из списка рецензий

Tags: обсуждение, локализация

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/701555/revisions

[image: скриншот]

Судя по всему, эта фраза используется когда сообщение удалено через очередь проверок.

Предлагаю поменять перевод.

Answer (score 7):

> Сообщение удалено голосованием в очереди проверок

Предлагаю такой вариант.

Comment: Поддерживаю. Оригинальная фраза звучит так: *"Post Deleted From Review"*

Comment: Тогда лучше "из очереди проверок", нет?

Comment: @Denis, та же проблема, что и у удалённого ответа. "Удалено из очереди" воспринимается как исключение из самой очереди, а не как использование очереди в качестве инструмента удаления.

Answer (score 1):

> Сообщение удалено через очередь проверок